# Consistent UID and GID across Linux clients for multiple domain using autorid

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba

This is my current setup:
I have 2 Active Directory servers (AD1 = TEST1) (AD2 = TEST2).AD2 is a trusted domain. And the samba version is 3.6.9-168.el6_5 .
I have successfully integrated my linux Clients (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5) to AD1 server with the below smb.conf file.I need consistent UID and GID for both the domain users TEST1 and TEST2. wibinfo -u and -g works fine for me with the below configuration for both the domains.I am able to get consistent UID and GID for the TEST1 domain. But for the TEST2 (trusted domain) , wbinfo -i shows the below error

```
# wbinfo -i TEST2\\user1
failed to call wbcGetpwnam: WBC_ERR_DOMAIN_NOT_FOUND
Could not get info for user user1
```

My current smb.conf file as below

```
[global]
        workgroup = TEST1
        realm = TEST1.LOCAL
        netbios name = LB001
        security = ads
        winbind offline logon = yes
        allow trusted domains = yes
        winbind enum users = yes
        winbind enum groups = yes
        winbind use default domain = yes
        winbind use default domain = yes
        template home dir = /home/%U

        idmap config * : backend = autorid
        idmap config * : range = 1000000-1999999

        template shell = /bin/bash
```

Need help to get the consistent UID and GID for both the domain with this autorid option.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `wbinfo -i` is a high-level tool that is testing nsswitch integration. Here much more than just Id-mapping can go wrong. The error message DOMAIN_NOT_FOUND is also misleading (bug in the wbinfo code).

The atomic testing of id-mapping would be this:

```
wbinfo -n TEST2\\user1
```

to give you the SID (windows user ID) for the user, and then use

```
wbinfo -S SID
```

with this sid to check UID assignment. Similarly, use

```
wbinfo -Y SID
```

if you are testing a group object.

That being said, you are not guaranteed to get the exact same configuration with idmap autorid, because it associates incrementing subranges of the defined overall range to the domains in the order they access the server.
So if you want to be 100% certain to have the exact same IDs, then you
should consider using an explicit configuration using the rid backend,
like so:

```
[global]
idmap config * : backend = tdb
idmap config * : range = 1000000-1999999
idmap config TEST1 : backend = rid
idmap config TEST1 : range = 2000000-2999999
idmap config TEST2 : backend = rid
idmap config TEST2 : range = 3000000-3999999
```